# Angular Module tree-shaking

Tags: angular

Suppose I have a module that imports a `CommonModule` that I have defined elsewhere in my app:

```
NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ComponentOne,
        ComponentTwo,
        ComponentThree
    ]
})
export class CommonModule {}
```

When I use this module elsewhere, via `imports` will *only* the component I use on my templates be included in the final bundle? In other words:

`<component-one></component-one>`

Will the final bundle only include this component? Does tree-shaking come into effect here?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to include all the components you need to reuse outside the module in the `exports` array as well.

Answer (score 0):

### Valid till Angular 8

All the components that are not a part of `entryComponents` will be removed with tree-shaking.

[entry components](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components#entrycomponents-and-the-compiler)

> In fact, many libraries declare and export components you'll never use. For example, a material design library will export all components because it doesn’t know which ones you will use. However, it is unlikely that you will use them all. For the ones you don't reference, the tree shaker drops these components from the final code package.
>
> If a component isn't an entry component and isn't found in a template, the tree shaker will throw it away. So, it's best to add only the components that are truly entry components to help keep your app as trim as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @aelagawy is right, in order to use the components you should export them

Please checkout the details right in the official docs in this [LINK](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules)

> Creating shared modules allows you to organize and streamline your
>   code. You can put commonly used directives, pipes, and components into
>   one module and then import just that module wherever you need it in
>   other parts of your app.

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomerComponent } from './customer.component';
import { NewItemDirective } from './new-item.directive';
import { OrdersPipe } from './orders.pipe';

@NgModule({
 imports:      [ CommonModule ],
 declarations: [ CustomerComponent, NewItemDirective, OrdersPipe ],
 exports:      [ CustomerComponent, NewItemDirective, OrdersPipe,
                 CommonModule, FormsModule ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

AGAIN for more details check this link
https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules